# Transition on leaving mouse

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I'm trying to make some transition.

At the moment my block has 3 parts :

1. base block
2. Hover image (coming from top)
3. Hover title (coming from bot)

On mouse hover, there also is a transition on the background-color that will change.

> Everything works when mouse arrives, and the goal is to make the same inverse animation when the cursor leaves.

```css
#studio {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50x;
}

#studio #portfolie {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#studio #portfolie .content-porfolio {
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto 140px;
}
#studio #portfolie .project-title--hover {
  bottom: -19px;
  transition: bottom .7s ease;
}
#studio #portfolie .project-logo--hover {
  margin-top: -100px;
  transition: margin-top 0.7s ease;
}
#studio #portfolie .md-trigger:hover .project-title--hover {
  display: block !important;
  bottom: 25px;
}
#studio #portfolie .md-trigger:hover .project-logo--hover {
  display: block !important;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: calc((25%-attr(height))/2);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#studio #portfolie .project-logo--base {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#studio #portfolie .hover-container {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#studio #portfolie .md-trigger:hover .hover-container {
  background-color: #F1CE34;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#studio #portfolie .content-play {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#studio #portfolie .content-play .slide {
  display: none;
}
#studio #portfolie .content-play > * {
  width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 40px);
}
#studio #portfolie .content-play .play {
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#studio #portfolie .content-play .play span {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Black';
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="studio">
<div id="portfolie">
<ul class="content-play clearfix grid-3">
  <li data-modal="modal-video-1" class="first play md-trigger slide" id="first-play" style="display: list-item;">
    <div class="project-logo--base" style="background-image: url(http://storage.tvanouvelles.ca/v1/dynamic_resize/sws_path/tvanouvelles_prod/bc7caa6d-8748-495c-8522-a7fc17513ce7_ORIGINAL.jpg?quality=80&size=800x&version=0)">
      <div class="hover-container">
        <div class="project-logo--hover" style="background-image: url(http://www.esoterisme-exp.com/File_images/2012/1205/Carre-bleu.png)"></div>
        <span class="project-title--hover">Tennis festival</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
```

[here is the same on CodePen because it looks easier to modify](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWRjVO)

Comment: Try This
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `:not(:hover)` pseudo class.

If your problem is that the blue square is not going back up then try it like this:

```
#studio #portfolie .project-logo--hover {
  top: -100px;
  transition: top .7s ease;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
}
#studio #portfolie .md-trigger:hover .project-title--hover {
  display: block !important;
  bottom: 25px;
}
#studio #portfolie .md-trigger:hover .project-logo--hover {
  display: block !important;
  top: calc((25%-attr(height))/2);
}
#studio #portfolie .hover-container {
  transition: background 0.7s linear;
  background-color: #FDF200;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#studio #portfolie .md-trigger:hover .hover-container {
  background-color: #F1CE34;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice css selector, but it is compatible with only [12% of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot) so it cannot be a solution for me here :/

Comment: I've editted my answer because it was too big for a comment

Comment: The top part slides out correctly now :) Last thing, the background looks to still instantly disappear ?

Comment: I re-editted my answer and changed the **hover-container** class so now the background color should be ok. In principle you should set all the building styles of the item on the normal state and on the hover state only the styles that change.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "Sweep to Top" background-transition [here](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) and [here](https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css). I think it could suit your needs.